# ¿Cómo podría escribir el código para que la función ordenar no me de error al recibir datos?

Tags: c, struct

Enunciado del ejercicio
Dada la estructura:

```
typedef struct
{
int a, b;
}
t_dosint;
```

Programar una función que intercambie los valores de los campos a y b de
una variable de este tipo que es externa a la presente función.(no se puede modificar la estructura).

Mi problema esta en

```
t_dosint intercambiar(t_dosint *(variables->x),t_dosint *(variables->y))
```

Y también me aparece que declare la función en forma implícita cuando ejecuto programa

Perdón si el error es muy tonto pero estuve bastante tiempo intentando hacer el ejercicio y no puedo lograr hacerlo bien

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
int x, y;
}
t_dosint;


t_dosint intercambiar(t_dosint *(variables->x),t_dosint *(variables->y))
{
    t_dosint aux;

    aux,variables->x;
    variables->x=variables->y;
    variables->y=aux;

    return *variables;
}

int main()
{
    t_dosint *variables=NULL;

    variables->x=5;
    variables->y=3;

    printf("x = %d  y = %d ",variables->x,variables->y);
    variables=intercambiar( &(variables->x) , &(variables->y)) ;
    printf("\nx = %d  y = %d ",variables->x,variables->y);
    return 0;
}
```

Desde ya gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variables=intercambiar( &(variables->x) , &(variables->y)) ;
```

La línea anterior no tiene ningún sentido:

- la función recibe dos parámetros (punteros) cuyos valores va a intercambiar
- la función devuelve ¿por qué? una estructura con los valores anteriores intercambiados

Es decir, estás haciendo dos veces lo mismo (vía parámetros y vía valor de retorno).

Si tu función recibe dos enteros, no debería retornar nada. ¿por qué? porque esos dos enteros pueden provenir de una estructura tipo `t_dosint` o de cualquier otro sitio:

```
int a = 10, b=5;
intercambiar(&a,&b); // ¿Por que crear una estructura en este caso?
```

Asumir que debes crear una estructura en este caso es mucho asumir. Así pues la línea en cuestión debería quedar así:

```
intercambiar(&variables->x , &variables->y);
```

Y ahora vamos a fijarnos en cómo está implementada:

```
t_dosint intercambiar(t_dosint *(variables->x),t_dosint *(variables->y))
```

Ya en la primera línea tenemos problemas. La función va a recibir como argumento dos enteros... no un puntero a los elementos `x` e `y` de `t_dosint` sino, simplemente, dos enteros. Además hemos dicho que no debería devolver nada... la declaración de la función queda entonces así:

```
void intercambiar(int* x, int* y)
```

¿Y la implementación? ahora resulta que tiene hasta tres líneas menos:

```
void intercambiar(int* x, int* y)
{
    int aux = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = aux;
}
```

Comment: Ya me funciono  gracias